# SQL: excluding look up

Tags: sql, many-to-many, self-join

I have such data structure:

[image: table]

I have to find all people who doesn't have `PHONE_TYPE = 2`

I solved this with such query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM table WHERE NAME NOT IN (
SELECT S2.NAME FROM table S2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table S1
ON S1.PHONE_TYPE != 2 AND S2.PHONE_TYPE = S1.PHONE_TYPE
WHERE S1.PHONE_TYPE is null);
```

- Is there more sophisticate approach?
- What is the standard solution for search when you have `many-to-many` relation?

Comment: What is your desire result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you would have three tables; it may be worth taking a look at what **referential integrity** is. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/data_int.htm

You would have the following tables: -

[image]

The reason I have split up into three tables is because I believe that your above data structure needs *normalizing*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

> 1. To free the collection of relations from undesirable insertion, update and deletion dependencies;
> 2. To reduce the need for restructuring the collection of relations, as new types of data are introduced, and thus increase the life span of application programs;
> 3. To make the relational model more informative to users;
> 4. To make the collection of relations neutral to the query statistics, where these statistics are liable to change as time goes by.
>      — E.F. Codd, "Further Normalization of the Data Base Relational Model"[8]

I would strongly recommend having primary keys for your person and phone type tables. I prefer surrogate keys, such as a UUID, but see http://sqlmag.com/business-intelligence/surrogate-key-vs-natural-key for determining what's best for your setup.

You could use the following query to then pull out rows: -

```
SELECT p.NAME FROM PERSON as p
WHERE p.id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM PersonPhone WHERE phone_id = 2)
```

You typically want to get rid of many-many relationships as you end up having redundant data in your database, which eventually could cause you some problems.

Comment: Why the hell would he split a table with two columns to 3 different tables? he have and needs only one table.

Comment: His example, seems to include a small test case of a person table which probably contains a lot more than just the name. We can clearly see in his question that there is duplicate information in the first table, thus having a join table removes redundant data - furthermore, the phone type probably would contain a lot more information that probably doesn't need to get repeated each time.

Comment: I agree with your points about normalisation (although your reference to "UUID" to me implies a GUID which [I don't necessarily agree with](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/disk-space-is-cheap/), although I may be jumping to conclusions), however the query at the end is not correct, it is retrieving all names that have a phone type that isn't 2, which is subtly different from names that don't have a phone type that is 2. With the sample data your query would return "Kolia" because of the record with phone type 4, but this should be excluded because there is a record with phone type 2.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood, fixed the query - with regard to your UUID/GUID query, that's probably up to him, whether he uses natural or surrogate.

Answer (score 3):

This is a task for NOT EXISTS:

```
select distinct name
from table as t1
where not exists
 ( select *
   from table as t2
   where t1.name = t2.name
     and t2.phone_type = 2
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this as well

```
select name from table
group by name having max(case when phone_type=2 then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use NOT IN condition like this:

```
SELECT * from table
where name not in(select name from table where phone_type = 2)
```